# How can I check the type of an upload file using Laravel + React?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, database, laravel

I am using React + Laravel. For upload file i using  Maatwebsite library. I'm just learning, so all this is for a "home project" :) There is a form with an input for selecting a file and a button:

```
<form>
  <input type="file" name="file" onChange={e => preUploadFile(e)} />
  <Button onClick={importFileHandler} disabled={!file}>Upload</Button>
</form>
```

I save the selected file to the state:

```
const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
const preUploadFile = e => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        setFile(file);
};
```

Then I "drop" state into fetch:

```
// post for import
export const importFileInDataBase = async file => {
    try {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);
        await fetch(`${url}/v2/organizations/import`, {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData
        }).then(response => {
            console.log("result", response);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

After that, I call this function by clicking on the button and alsoby clicking on the button I call the function, which will request data from the table with a get request and render it on the page.

```
const importFileHandler = () => {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(importFileInDataBase(file));
    }).then(() => {
        getAllOrganizations();
    });
};
```

My Model on the back-end:

```
class ScheduledInspectionModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'scheduled_inspection';
    protected $fillable = ['name_smp', 'name_control', "verification_start", "verification_end", 'verification_duration'];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Controller:

```
class OrganizationsImportController extends Controller
{
    public function import(Request $request)
    {
        // return dd($request->file);
        Excel::import(new OrganizationsImport, $request->file);
        return response()->json('Success upload');
    }
}
```

And file with setting for import:

```
class OrganizationsImport implements ToModel
{
    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new ScheduledInspectionModel([
            'name_smp' => $row[0],
            'name_control' => $row[1],
            'verification_start' => $row[2],
            'verification_end' => $row[3],
            'verification_duration' => $row[4],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Please tell me how i can\need to check the type of the imported file (only the .xls file is needed)? PS: another question, I would like to display some message about successful import or not. I in the controller return the message `response () -> json ('Import completed');` how can I get use with this? PSS: maybe it comes in handy somehow `dd($ response);`:

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#282
  -test: false
  -originalName: "test.xls"
  -mimeType: "application/vnd.ms-excel"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "/tmp"
  filename: "phpzFcBzS"
  basename: "phpzFcBzS"
  pathname: "/tmp/phpzFcBzS"
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/tmp/phpzFcBzS"
  aTime: 2020-08-25 14:39:02
  mTime: 2020-08-25 14:39:02
  cTime: 2020-08-25 14:39:02
  inode: 318670
  size: 6144
  perms: 0100600
  owner: 1000
  group: 1000
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

Comment: FWIW: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57856/is-there-a-way-to-check-the-filetype-of-a-file-uploaded-using-php

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the file input's [`accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) attribute.

```
<input type="file" name="file" accept=".xls,application/vnd.ms-excel" onChange="..." />
```

This will only allow you to select .xls files when you click the button.

Comment: Yeah, well it looks like he's got the back end covered already. I'd be suprised if `Excel::import()` was able to import something other than a spreadsheet.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. I'd still mention the danger for future visitors :)

Comment: Agreed. Check extension, check mime type, restrict as much as you can, and still never trust. OWASP has always been a good source for these topics: https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Unrestricted_File_Upload

Comment: @ficuscr - **Everything** your app sends to the server is an exercise in trust. You can't guarantee the safety of anything the browser sends to the client. No amount of Jaavscript code or anything  else on the client can change that. This isn't going to help with potential security issues, it's a UX improvement. His back end is covered by virtue of how the file is being parsed.